# read xml output from php and store it in variables

Tags: php, xml

I want to store all the values under domorder using php,like following array variable, in xml file sometime $tld[veribal][$i] may have more then one values
Note : the xml file if coming from url

```
$tld[0] = dombiz;
$tld[dombiz][0] = biz;
$tld[1] = dominfo;
$tld[dominfo][0] = info;
```

xml file :

```
<hashtable>
    <entry>
    <string>domorder</string>
    <map-array>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dombiz</string>
          <vector>
            <string>biz</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dominfo</string>
          <vector>
            <string>info</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domcno</string>
          <vector>
            <string>com</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domorg</string>
          <vector>
            <string>org</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domus</string>
          <vector>
            <string>us</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>donutsgroup2</string>
          <vector>
            <string>fish</string>
            <string>chat</string>
            <string>associates</string>
            <string>media</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dotlove</string>
          <vector>
            <string>love</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </map-array>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>digicert</string>
    <string-array/>
  </entry>
</hashtable>
```

Comment: And what? We should write code for you?

Comment: read xml, select all `<map>` by xpath `//map`,  take name with `.//entry/string/text()` then in foreach use xpath `.//vector/string/text()` to receive all string under map

Answer (score 0):

This code prints only `dombiz` and `biz` but you can iterate.

```
    $myXMLData = "<hashtable>
    <entry>
    <string>domorder</string>
    <map-array>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dombiz</string>
          <vector>
            <string>biz</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dominfo</string>
          <vector>
            <string>info</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domcno</string>
          <vector>
            <string>com</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domorg</string>
          <vector>
            <string>org</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>domus</string>
          <vector>
            <string>us</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>donutsgroup2</string>
          <vector>
            <string>fish</string>
            <string>chat</string>
            <string>associates</string>
            <string>media</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
      <map>
        <entry>
          <string>dotlove</string>
          <vector>
            <string>love</string>
          </vector>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </map-array>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>digicert</string>
    <string-array/>
  </entry>
</hashtable>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$tld = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print($tld['entry'][0]['map-array']['map'][0]['entry']['string']); // dombiz
print('<br />');
print($tld['entry'][0]['map-array']['map'][0]['entry']['vector']['string']); // biz
```